# Is there any option to send core files to a remote location without storing them locally?

Tags: linux, core-dump

I understand we can use `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to configure the core file name, is there a way to mention a remote path, or mounting the network drive is the only option?

My system does not have enough flash to save cores, I want to write the core to remote location from RAM.

Comment: check out abrt  (http://linux.die.net/man/8/abrtd) on linux - it can be configured to save and upload core dumps.